# Jquery accordion activate from external links

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, accordion

I am having a lot of trouble trying to open certain J query UI accordion sections from external links. I am calling form functions from hyperlinks.

Links are opening sections but then they click back to original position. any help would be much appreciated. Here the source.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
            autoHeight: false,
        });
    });
</script>


<script>
function Clicked1(){  
$("#accordion").accordion('activate' , 0)
 } 

 function Clicked2(){  
$("#accordion").accordion('activate' , 1)
 } 

</script>


<div class="demo">

<a href="" onclick="Clicked1()">OPEN1</a>
<a href="" onclick="Clicked2()">OPEN2</a>



<div id="accordion">
    <h3>< href="#section1" >Section 1</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, susceros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.</p>
    </div>

</div>

</div><!-- End demo -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the API of accordion, you should use:

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({ active: 2 });
```

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion

Answer (score 1):

I made your example work by putting an actual tag into the href you did the `onclick` for, as:

```
<a href="#section1" onclick="clicked2()">;
```

Answer (score 0):

Write accordion code

```
collapsible: true
```