# Activating accordion panels from external anchors/links

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I've been trying for some time to activate a jQuery UI accordion's panel from an external link.

I have links within pages that an accordion widget is on that I'd like to use to activate panels of the accordion. These links are not within the accordion widget's markup.

These links are manipulating tab interactivity and are used for popping in AJAX content.
At some states of the application, the { navigation: true } part of my options object for the accordion gets forgotten.
I believe this is because I'm initiating a window.reload.location() to get back to certain states of the application.

The function below shows this. What I think I need is either a custom navigation filter built on hashes, or location that will work within this function to also activate accordion panels depending on what URL the user is on. 
I do have navigation set to true in the beginning of my scripts and the following script comes later...

```
// "Back to xxxtabTitle" button used to revert tabs to their default state after    
// photoNav pop-in AJAX content has been loaded
$('#mainContent').on('click', '.backToInitTab', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location.reload();

  // accordion navigation filter to open correct accordion panel on click event
    // Can you help with this? I'd greatly appreciate it.
  // /accordion navigation filter
    });

// /"Back to xxxtabTitle" button
```

Any help or insight on this issue would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance.
Sincerely,
Dick Kirkland

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of the answer: I had to abandon using navigation options with the jQuery UI accordion as I'm using a design on a site that contains buttons that perform reloads on pages and/or UI tab panels with window.location.reload();. If you have this reloading of content in your site, you may see the navigation begin to take effect by opening up the desired accordion panel, but then seeing the panel contracting. I believe this is because normally, clicks from the accordion panel itself instruct the UI accordion component how to react to the hash history. We turned navigation off and did manual instantiations of what panels should open on a minimum of pages. This allows AJAX functionality (tabbed content) to still have the accordion panels open and the only animation seen is when the total page reloads.

Answer (score 0):

write

$( "#accordion" ).accordion({ active: 2 });

refer to [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140938/jquery-accordion-activate-from-external-links)

Comment: This answer is also helpful. I could only mark one and the full explanation of your code plus other things are above. Thank you!